# curl command fails with a timeout

Tags: 12.04, proxy, curl

I'm trying to run the following command on my ubuntu box:

```
 curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

It times out.

I tried to ping the address but it just sits there.
I also tried to ping google.com but again, it just sits there. 
I don't think it's a DNS issue... here's the output from the ping:

```
 me@mydev:/var/www/wtracks$ ping google.com
 PING google.com (74.125.226.134) 56(84) bytes of data.
 ^C
 --- google.com ping statistics ---
 1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

 me@mydev:/var/www/wtracks$ ping 74.125.226.134
 PING 74.125.226.134 (74.125.226.134) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

What I've tried so far:
I've opened up my proxy settings in chrome (which is what I'm using right now to surf...) and made sure that I ran the following command in the command line where I'm trying to run curl:

```
 export http_proxy="http://myproxyservername.net:8080"
```

Then i retried the ping and curl but neither work. 
Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are tying to use a `http_proxy` environment variable with HTTPS url `https://install.meteor.com/` .

To set your HTTPS proxy use `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable  (all upper case)

from manual for curl

> Curl reads and understands the following environment variables:
>
> ```
>     http_proxy, HTTPS_PROXY, FTP_PROXY
> ```