# curl command fails with time out when downloading meteor

Tags: 14.04, proxy, curl

I'm having the same issue described here: 
[curl command fails with a timeout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546008/curl-command-fails-with-a-timeout)
The solution says to define the https proxy variable with all upper case letters.

This is what I've tried:

```
me@medev:~$ export HTTPS_PROXY="http://myproxy.bb.org:8080"
me@medev:~$
```

But when I try to do the curl command it sits there for up to 5 minutes with no progress 
being made...

**Other Tests I tried**

Interestingly, I cannot ping yahoo.ca but I can do a wget on it and it grabs the index.html file. 
Not savvy enough to know what this means though...

**Edit 1**

```
$ sudo curl https://install.meteor.com | sh
```

Comment: Are you using https protocol? Could you post curl command you did?

Comment: @Letizia please see my edit 1 in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `sudo` in the wrong place, doubly so:

1. `sudo` resets some environment variables, so your `HTTPS_PROXY` is not reaching `curl` in the first place.
2. The `sh` command should be run with `sudo`, if the script needs it.

Do:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com | sudo sh
```